# AVAudioSession, how to invert audiowave from microphone stream?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have a AVAudioSession instantiated. I need to inverse the amplitude of the session, but I don't find any function that does it from the AVAudioSession properties.

Shall I use a different framework to get some properties from my audiostream from my microphone to the speaker? If so how?

The simplest thing would just to multiply the audio waveform with -1 to get the inverse, but I cant find the property that holds the audio amplitude.

Best regards 
Marcus